# Populating database table with strict conditions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table named B1 and another called R1. Table R1 has a foreign key to B1 primary key that is of type integer. Table B1 has 10,000 records and table R1 is to have 1,000,000 records however records in table R1 need to have the foreign key set with distinct B1 primary key of 7,000; no more no less. Now I have some ideas how to do this, however it is quite complex and potentially take a lot of time to do. Is there maybe a formula to calculate this in a simpler way? For this I am using PostgreSQL. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How can 1000000 records have only 7000 distinct values for the foreign key : only 7000 rows have a non-null value for that foreign key and all the other rows have a null value ?

Comment: Yes you can. You can have a value in the foreign key repeated more than once since it is a 1 to Many relationship

Comment: Please share the sample dataset and what are the available values count in the primary key column